# How to organize angular js code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a project using Angular as front end framework. I put all my code into abc.js under this format:

```
(function(){

    var globalVariable1;
    var globalVariable2;
    var globalVariable3;
    var globalVariable4;

    var myApp = angular.module('coolapp',[]);

    myApp.controller('Controller1', [$scope, $rootScope, function(){
           //blah blah
    }]);

    myApp.factory('Factory1', function(){
           //blah blah
    });
    //....
})();
```

Now it is more than 500 lines with quite a few global variables.

I plan to separate them into different files. What should I do? Let's say I created

main.js

```
(function(){

    var globalVariable1;
    var globalVariable2;
    var globalVariable3;
    var globalVariable4;

    var myApp = angular.module('coolapp',[]);


})();
```

Controller1.js

```
(function(){

    var myApp = angular.module('coolapp');

    myApp.controller('Controller1', [$scope, $rootScope, function(){
           //blah blah
    }]);

})();
```

What should I write in main.js to require or include or inject(not sure what is the difference between them) Controller1.js?

Comment: To add some specificity to the good comments below, with the global variables, you should register those as services with Angular using module.value or module.factory, and then you can inject them into components defined in other files.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create another module which handle your all controllers and provide dependency to your main module:-

```
main.js

var myApp = angular.module('coolapp',['cntrlApp']);

Controller1.js

var myApp = angular.module('cntrlApp');
 myApp.controller('Controller1', [$scope, $rootScope, function(){
           //blah blah
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your way is the right way. You also can look on RequireJS

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your project is going to continue to grow, I would suggest looking in to using require.js with Typescript. We've implemented that and it has greatly increased the robustness of our code, and it's much easier to manage and refactor our code.

Then depending on how complex your application is going to be you might look at structuring it in to a domain model, and then views, services, etc.... Obviously a lot of this depends on how complex of a project you're building and where you think you're project is going.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of opinions of how to best structure an Angular app. You seem to be headed in a good direction. Here's how I prefer to do it:

In your **index.html**, include your scripts individually. The self-invoking anonymous functions will set themselves up with Angular. Use a build process like Grunt or Gulp to minify and concatenate these later.

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="Controller1.js"></script>
<script src="Factory1.js"></script>
```

In your **main.js** (I call it app.js typically, I think it's user prefererence).

```
(function() {

  'use strict';


  angular
    .module('MyApp', [
      // any module dependencies
    ]);


})();
```

In your **Controller1.js**, set up your controller, define it as an Angular controller and part of the application.

```
(function() {

  'use strict';


  angular
    .module('MyApp')
    .controller('Controller1', Controller1);


  function Controller1($scope) {
    // do something
  }


})();
```

In your **Factory1.js**, set up your factory function and define it as an Angular factory and part of the application.

```
(function() {

  'use strict';


  angular
    .module('MyApp')
    .controller('Factory1', Factory1);


  function Factory1() {
    return function() {
      // return something
    };
  }


})();
```

After that, there isn't much to do. My main.js usually has a config function in it and handles the routing. You can initialize the app by adding the `ng-app="MyApp"` to your `html` or `body`. You can initialize your Controller1 simply by adding the attribute `ng-controller="Controller1"` to an element in your DOM. If you need Factory1 to be accessible by Controller1, then when you define the function Controller1 in **Controller1.js**, do it like so `function Controller1($scope, Factory1) {}`.

That's all you really need to get it up and running with separate files.